# Blank Frontend and Backend of Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento and I am trying to learn it. I installed Magento using CLI and it got installed successfully, but when I navigated to my frontend, nothing was shown, attaching a screenshot below

[image]

Same is the case with backend, below is the image for backend

[image]

Please help me with this
Thank you all in advance

EDIT

After running 3 commands, mentioned in the below answer, the screen looks like

[image]

Comment: Did you run the upgrade and static-content:deploy commands?

Comment: @SufyanKhot no, can you help with that please?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands from your magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Also give permissions to var/* pub/* and generated/*

Comment: trying this right now, Thanks for help, I'll let you know if this works

Comment: After running those 3 commands, it looks alot better but still no content is shown. I've edited the question and have added the third screenshot after running those 3 commands

Comment: Is the admin page still blank?

Comment: yes, but instead of being white like before, It now have a brown color, but still blank